# How can Schema.org markup be worth implementing if Google and Microsoft don't use it on their own websites?

Tags: google, microdata, structured-data, microsoft

Google appears to have

```html
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en">
```

along with a meta tag for an image; searching microsoft.com’s source HTML code finds no matches for `itemt` or `itemp`.

Should I even worry about using Schema.org or Dublin Core or any type of meta markup? It appears that the backers of Schema.org don’t even use it.

Answer (score 4):

What makes it worthwhile providing metadata?

The fact that companies like Google and Microsoft *provide* this metadata [also themselves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food)? Or the fact that these companies *make use* of the metadata you provide?

The Schema.org sponsor’s search engines provide no (Bing, Yahoo, Yandex) to little (Google) metadata using the Schema.org vocabulary, and this might have various reasons (for example, they might not like/allow that some other party/tool parses their SERPs, so why make it easier?), but none of their reasons should stop *you* providing it. Big company websites rarely serve as good examples for HTML best practices.

So you just have to decide: *Do I want to enable humans and machines to make better use of my content by providing metadata?* Your answer should not depend on who else is doing it, but on who is consuming it.

And as a side note: If you want to find out if a webpage is using the Schema.org vocabulary, searching for "itemt" and "itemp" is not sufficient. This would give results if the Microdata syntax is used, but there are other syntaxes for making use of vocabularies like Schema.org, e.g. RDFa, JSON-LD, Turtle etc.

Comment: I searched for the JSON-LD keywords as well.  It seems like they would offer some incentive to use the schema.org since they promote it.  Maybe some kind of acknowledgement, an icon in search results indicating structured data, or a free t-shirt :-)  I guess the next question is Dublin Core or schema.org?

Comment: @RonRoyston: Dublin Core or Schema.org? It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to provide as much data as possible, there is no reason to stop there … [there are so many vocabularies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669), and depending on your domain, you might have to [create your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21162395/1591669), too. But if you only care about the major search engines and things like Rich Snippets, you can stay with Schema.org, as this is the only vocabulary they seem to support currently.